# Sort lists according to the order of another

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have three parallel lists (i.e. the elements in position i of each list are related). I want to sort the first list using the function `Sort` and make the same changes to the other lists so that I still have parallel lists when finished.

How can I do this?

As an example:
Given the lists `{2, 3, 1}`, `{a, b, c}`, and `{alpha, beta, gamma}`, sorting all lists according the first one gives `{1, 2, 3}`, `{c, a, b}`, and `{gamma, alpha, beta}`.

Comment: I feel like this could be done by MMA 10's `Association`. Could anyone implement one? I set up the association: `AssociationThread[{2, 3, 1} -> Transpose@{{a, b, c}, {alpha, beta, gamma}}]`, but not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
lists = {list1, list2, list3} = {{1, 3, 2}, {a, b, c}, {x, y, z}};
```

Another option

```
SortBy[lists\[Transpose], First]\[Transpose]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {a, c, b}, {x, z, y}}

Comment: Why is `\[Transpose]` necessary?

Comment: @TysonWilliams `\[Transpose]` is a nice notation (see it in the front end) for the matrix `Transpose` function. You first create a single list such that it's i'th element is {list1[[i]], list2[[i]], list3[[i]]}. Then, you sort that list just by looking at its elemtents' first elements

Comment: In other words, you start off with a matrix in which each ROW its one of your lists (thats `lists`), and you transpose it, and now your lists are the columns. Now you sort the rows of that matrix just by looking at the frist column, and transpose again

Comment: `Transpose` is usually a very efficient operation

Comment: I accepted this solution since it is inline.

Answer (score 37):

You can use combination of `Part` and `Ordering` as

```
list1[[ Ordering @ list2 ]]
```

to sort `list1` in the order of `list2`.

Examples:

```
{list1, list2, list3} = {{1, 3, 2}, {a, b, c}, {x, y, z}};
list2[[ Ordering @ list1 ]]
```

gives

```
{a, c, b}
```

and

```
list3[[ Ordering @ list1 ]]
```

gives

```
{x, z, y}
```

EDIT: Using with lists of lists, to sort the entire array based on the first list:

```
list = {list1, list2, list3};
list[[ All, Ordering @ list[[1]] ]]
```

gives

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {a, c, b}, {x, z, y}}
```

But ... as I just noticed, this is already covered in @Mr.Wizard's answer long before my edit.

Comment: Very good. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @TysonWilliams, my pleasure..

Answer (score 24):

`Ordering` and `Part` is more efficient than `SortBy` and `Transpose` and it can also be done in one pass as I will demonstrate.

I create three lists of different type as described in the question:

```
a = RandomInteger[999, 500];
b = RandomReal[1, 500];
c = CharacterRange["a", "z"] ~RandomChoice~ 500;
```

I use the [`timeAvg`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199042/618728) function for testing:

```
SortBy[{a, b, c}\[Transpose], First]\[Transpose] // timeAvg

{a, b, c}[[All, Ordering@a]] // timeAvg
```

> 0.00027456
>
> 0.000026944

As can be seen second method is more than an order of magnitude faster on this data.

It is noteworthy that these two forms as shown *do not* perform the same operation because `SortBy[list, func]` is not a stable sort.  Observe:

```
lists = {{8, 8, 6, 3, 7},
         {"i", "e", "f", "b", "m"},
         {"q", "x", "u", "w", "z"}};

SortBy[lists\[Transpose], First]\[Transpose]

lists[[All, Ordering @ First @ lists]]
```

> ```
> {{3, 6, 7, 8, 8}, {"b", "f", "m", "e", "i"}, {"w", "u", "z", "x", "q"}}
>
> {{3, 6, 7, 8, 8}, {"b", "f", "m", "i", "e"}, {"w", "u", "z", "q", "x"}}
> ```

You can see see that `SortBy` has swapped the positions of `"i"`/`"e"` and `"q"`/`"x"` in the lists so it is not a minimal reordering.  This can be corrected however with [a different syntax for `SortBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332690/618728):

```
SortBy[lists\[Transpose], {First}]\[Transpose]
```

> ```
> {{3, 6, 7, 8, 8}, {"b", "f", "m", "i", "e"}, {"w", "u", "z", "q", "x"}}
> ```

This syntax also speeds up `SortBy`, but not enough to be competitive with `Ordering`:

```
SortBy[{a, b, c}\[Transpose], {First}]\[Transpose] // timeAvg
```

> 0.0001248

Answer (score 5):

This is a **more general solution** that I came up with some time ago to solve some rearrangement problems. I'm pretty sure that it is slower than any of the solutions above (as it uses `ReplacePart`), but it is general enough to deal with any kind of ragged partitions. Usage: `partitionAs` sorts and partitions a list just as a reference list `ref` is ordered and partitioned.

```
partitionAs[list_, ref_] := Module[{ord = Ordering@Flatten@ref, 
    pos = Position[ref, Except[_List | List]]}, 
   ReplacePart[ref, Thread[pos -> Flatten[list][[ord]]]]];

ref = {{2, {9}, 0}, {3, 7}, 6, {4, {8, 5}, 1}}
list = {"A", "B", {"C", "D"}, "E", {"F", "G"}, "H", "I", "J"};

partitionAs[list, ref]
```

> `{{2, {9}, 0}, {3, 7}, 6, {4, {8, 5}, 1}}`
>
> `{{"C", {"J"}, "A"}, {"D", "G"}, "I", {"F", {"E", "H"}, "B"}}`