# Sorting Eigensystems

Tags: list-manipulation

SO I have this code:

```
{evalueb1,evectorsb1} = Eigensystem[Coefficientsp1];
 evalueb1 = 1/(evalueb1*2\[Pi]);

 For[i=1,i<(2TruncationOrder+1),i++,If[Abs[Im[evalueb1[[i]]]]                                            
 <10^-14,evalueb1[[i]]=Re[evalueb1[[i]]],evalueb1[[i]]=evalueb1[[i]]]];

 \[Rho]plus1 = Sort[Select[evalueb1,Im[#]>0\[Or](Im[#]==0\[And]Re[#]>0)&],Im[#2]>Im[#1]&];
 \[Rho]minus1 = Sort[Select[evalueb1,Im[#]<0\[Or](Im[#]==0\[And]Re[#]<0)&],Im[#2]Im[#1]&];
```

What I did was sort the eigenvalues based on the sign of the complex part.  How can I make it so that I can find the correct eigenvector associated with the sorted eigenvalues?

Comment: Why not pair up your eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and then sort those pairs?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7679/5

Comment: How could I do that?  I sort the eigenvalues based on which Imaginary part is smaller.  Would that change the eigenvalues as well?

Comment: I also use Select[] to pick certain eigenvalues.  So could I pair them up some how and pick an eigenvector with the eigenvalue?

Comment: Have you seen the post rm linked to? (It would now seem that this is a dupe of that question.)