# How to sort eigenvalues?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, sorting

I am trying to find Eigenvalues to a 12x12 Matrix ($H$) dependent on two variables $x$ and $y$. Later I want to do a 3D plot of one eigenvalue ($E$) over $x$ and $y$.

An analytical solution is not possible so what I calculate a `Table` of numerical solutions and a `ListPlot`:

```
Solution = Table[
              Table[{x, y, N[Eigenvalue[H[x, y]]][[E]]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}], 
              {E, 1, 12}
           ];

ListPlot3D[{Solution[[1]]}]
```

My Problem: apparently every time the eigenvalues to $H$ for a specific $x$ and $y$ is found, the order of eigenvalues is not the same as before. So if I do the `ListPlot3D[{Solution[[1]]}]` I don't actually plot the eigenvalue 1 of $H$ but points of different eigenvalues of $H$.

So my question: How can I assign an order to my eigenvalues so that I know which value belongs to which eigenstate?

(Here you can find a link to the 12x12 matrix: http://pastebin.com/kUX4gdk8)

Comment: Please share your 12x12 matrix as well. Also, take a look at ([59172](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59172/27951)), ([63003](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63003/27951)), and ([25743](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25743/27951)).

Comment: The matrix is to long by 8400 characters... The matrix is hermitian with constants on the diagonal and big expressions depending on x and y on the off diagonal elements. The proposed answers seam only to order the eigenvalues depending on their values which does not help me.

Comment: You should add your matrix to your original question (use the edit link underneath it) or, perhaps preferentially, paste it somewhere online (e.g. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)) and provide a link to download it.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83906/2079

Comment: @george2079 I got the exact same problem but in a 3D situation. I have dificulties understanding and complete the code for the 3D situation. How long will this calculation approximatly take? (10 minutes or 3days?)

Comment: Related:  [this answer.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109444/27813)  The technique described there may be painfully slow in your case, but it may be the best you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Eigenvalues are ordered by their magnitude in general. If you want to preserve the order all over the region, the only way (as much I know) is to try to get an analytical expression. For example consider this simple matrix

```
H[x_, y_] = {{0, Cos[x] + Cos[y]}, {Cos[x] + Cos[y], 0}}
```

If I go with analytical expression

```
ev = Eigenvalues[H[x,y]];
Plot3D[Evaluate[ev], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

The eigenvalues are properly ordered. But if you try to evaluate it numerically. It will always be reordered.

```
data = Flatten[ Table[Join[{x, y}, Eigenvalues[H[x, y]] // N]
   , {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2., 2., 0.1}], 1];
data1 = Table[data[[All, {1, 2, 2 + n}]], {n, 2}];
ListPlot3D[data1]
```

[image]

Comment: I believe that the OP is interested in the case where the surfaces intersect one another.

Comment: Yes indeed. surfaces might inteesct or even be degenerate for a volume in space

Comment: I just took a simple matrix for example. The algorithm will work for any matrix. For a simple case try `H[x_, y_] = {{0, Cos[x] + Cos[y]}, {Cos[x] + Cos[y], 0}}`.

Comment: This method has no use for me because I need to see the real development of one Eigenvalue. Intersections and the right color coding is essential for the interpretation of my results.