# How do I sort complex numbers?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

Okay, so I posted something about sorting, and it was linked as a duplicate to [This post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7679/sort-lists-according-to-the-order-of-another?lq=1)
However, I am having problems trying to sort a list that contains both real and complex numbers.  I put them into one big list and used `SortBy[]` but that does not sort the complex numbers as I want them to.  Any ideas?  I can post what code I am using if that helps.

EDIT:: Data

```
A=
 {{0.651301, 0.671298, -0.000107956 + 0.735512 I, 
  9.93642*10^-6 + 0.764605 I, 0.965926, 0.97048, 0.0344992 + 1.4214 I,
   0.0028631 + 1.4505 I, -0.0626803 + 1.78014 I, -0.12443 + 1.98252 I,
   0.167724 + 
   2.24691 I}, {{-6.79317*10^-6 - 2.8086*10^-6 I, -0.0000157028 + 
    0.0000511297 I, 0.000393492 + 0.0000998273 I, 
   0.000323404 - 0.00221263 I, -0.0140581 - 0.00161283 I, 
   0.00034936 + 0.0455525 I, 0.227164 - 6.59195*10^-17 I, 
   0.000350353 + 0.0494098 I, 0.0042655 - 0.0016156 I, 
   0.000351651 + 0.00161694 I, -2.50028*10^-6 - 
    0.0000297226 I, -0.0000277994 - 0.0000114935 I, -0.0000642597 + 
    0.000209235 I, 0.00161027 + 0.000408518 I, 
   0.00132345 - 0.00905464 I, -0.0575294 - 0.00660009 I, 
   0.00142967 + 0.186412 I, 0.929613 + 0. I, 0.00143373 + 0.202197 I, 
   0.0174555 - 0.00661145 I, 
   0.00143904 + 0.00661691 I, -0.0000102317 - 
    0.000121632 I}, {0.000325231 - 0.00225856 I, -0.0141806 - 
    0.00160866 I, 0.000361568 + 0.0454971 I, 
   0.220155 - 6.245*10^-17 I, 0.000362024 + 0.0494813 I, 
   0.00410192 - 0.00161389 I, 
   0.000363184 + 0.00165808 I, -6.77596*10^-6 - 0.000030037 I, 
   0.0000121624 + 0.0000262499 I, -1.0809*10^-6 + 2.11658*10^-8 I, 
   1.98638*10^-7 + 2.53517*10^-7 I, 
   0.00137179 - 0.00952634 I, -0.0598123 - 0.00678514 I, 
   0.00152505 + 0.191902 I, 0.92859 + 0. I, 0.00152698 + 0.208706 I, 
   0.0173014 - 0.0068072 I, 
   0.00153187 + 0.00699361 I, -0.0000285803 - 0.000126693 I, 
   0.0000512998 + 0.000110719 I, -4.55912*10^-6 + 8.92749*10^-8 I, 
   8.37833*10^-7 + 1.06931*10^-6 I}, {-0.00936005 - 0.00689504 I, 
   0.00194175 + 0.0457214 I, -0.0000294616 - 
    0.200724 I, -0.00204752 + 0.0455102 I, 
   0.00912273 - 0.00677289 I, -0.00206909 + 0.000712454 I, 
   0.000308104 + 0.000136869 I, -0.0000338275 - 0.0000413905 I, 
   6.69395*10^-8 + 6.60345*10^-6 I, 
   4.55605*10^-7 - 7.51471*10^-7 I, -8.81591*10^-8 + 3.57016*10^-8 I, 
   0.0318708 - 0.0432515 I, -0.211296 + 0.00894252 I, 
   0.927617 + 0. I, -0.210317 - 0.0094932 I, 
   0.0312938 + 0.042164 I, -0.0032911 - 0.0095625 I, -0.000632731 + 
    0.00142376 I, 
   0.000191303 - 0.000156301 I, -0.0000305169 + 3.04872*10^-7 I, 
   3.47251*10^-6 + 2.10602*10^-6 I, -1.6493*10^-7 - 
    4.07439*10^-7 I}, {-5.0264*10^-7 - 
    8.58797*10^-7 I, -2.37939*10^-7 + 7.30947*10^-6 I, 
   0.0000371583 - 0.0000443393 I, -0.000328693 + 0.00013847 I, 
   0.0021433 + 0.000752547 I, -0.00910293 - 0.00695052 I, 
   0.0021046 + 0.0453582 I, 
   2.50419*10^-6 - 0.192697 I, -0.00210251 + 0.0453522 I, 
   0.00910842 - 0.00696524 I, -0.00217144 + 0.000743651 I, 
   4.12576*10^-6 - 2.41481*10^-6 I, -0.0000351158 - 1.14264*10^-6 I, 
   0.000213015 + 0.000178511 I, -0.00066525 - 
    0.00157909 I, -0.00361522 + 0.0102968 I, 
   0.0333908 - 0.0437323 I, -0.217908 + 0.0101137 I, 
   0.925747 + 0. I, -0.217879 - 0.010098 I, 
   0.0334627 + 0.0437578 I, -0.00357275 - 
    0.0104319 I}, {-0.0000358944 + 0.000126095 I, 
   0.000744548 + 0.000168628 I, 
   0.000462218 - 0.00346567 I, -0.0160687 - 0.00154484 I, 
   0.000533786 + 0.0440688 I, 0.147403 + 6.93889*10^-17 I, 
   0.000538762 + 0.0497767 I, 0.00157728 - 0.00155399 I, 
   0.000527326 + 0.00215325 I, -0.000121227 - 0.0000164675 I, 
   0.0000226836 + 0.0000418986 I, -0.000217846 + 0.000765279 I, 
   0.00451873 + 0.00102342 I, 
   0.00280524 - 0.0210335 I, -0.0975223 - 0.00937576 I, 
   0.0032396 + 0.267458 I, 0.894604 + 0. I, 0.0032698 + 0.302099 I, 
   0.00957266 - 0.00943131 I, 
   0.00320039 + 0.0130683 I, -0.000735739 - 0.0000999426 I, 
   0.000137669 + 0.000254286 I}, {0.000740075 + 0.000166838 I, 
   0.000463177 - 0.00347749 I, -0.0160926 - 0.0015432 I, 
   0.000536526 + 0.0440383 I, 0.146592 - 1.38778*10^-17 I, 
   0.000541552 + 0.049773 I, 0.00153733 - 0.00155267 I, 
   0.000529806 + 0.00215943 I, -0.000123573 - 0.0000161104 I, 
   0.0000229325 + 0.0000423765 I, -4.68374*10^-6 + 1.27897*10^-6 I, 
   0.00451276 + 0.00101733 I, 
   0.00282432 - 0.0212047 I, -0.0981278 - 0.00940995 I, 
   0.00327157 + 0.268533 I, 0.893872 + 0. I, 0.00330223 + 0.303501 I, 
   0.0093742 - 0.00946775 I, 
   0.0032306 + 0.0131676 I, -0.000753512 - 0.0000982366 I, 
   0.000139836 + 0.0002584 I, -0.00002856 + 
    7.79878*10^-6 I}, {0.00919186 + 0.0428642 I, 
   0.00225897 - 0.0930717 I, -0.00582016 + 0.0395705 I, 
   0.00877203 - 0.00965772 I, -0.00354763 + 0.00153788 I, 
   0.000872782 + 0.000117415 I, -0.000154478 - 0.000120785 I, 
   0.0000131793 + 0.0000345226 I, 
   1.35683*10^-6 - 6.59455*10^-6 I, -7.61336*10^-7 + 8.03641*10^-7 I, 
   1.70839*10^-7 - 3.9198*10^-8 I, -0.380824 + 0.0913832 I, 
   0.831706 + 0. I, -0.354663 - 0.0434019 I, 
   0.0881538 + 0.0762489 I, -0.0145037 - 0.0313503 I, -0.00085944 + 
    0.0078202 I, 
   0.00104523 - 0.00140582 I, -0.000305462 + 0.000125187 I, 
   0.0000591896 + 0.0000106883 I, -7.34228*10^-6 - 6.62524*10^-6 I, 
   3.87106*10^-7 + 1.51725*10^-6 I}, {7.99461*10^-7 + 
    8.43966*10^-7 I, -1.30319*10^-6 - 6.8308*10^-6 I, -0.0000142133 + 
    0.0000348017 I, 
   0.000159864 - 0.000116815 I, -0.000870595 + 0.0000850061 I, 
   0.00342612 + 0.00169007 I, -0.00817676 - 0.00973414 I, 
   0.0032317 + 0.0383895 I, 
   0.000181951 - 0.0921798 I, -0.00259292 + 0.0392848 I, 
   0.00884829 - 0.0104629 I, -7.67732*10^-6 + 7.30127*10^-6 I, 
   0.0000622308 - 0.0000119998 I, -0.00031743 - 0.00012891 I, 
   0.0010675 + 0.00145486 I, -0.000790386 - 
    0.00793286 I, -0.0153412 + 0.0312552 I, 
   0.0885675 - 0.0746961 I, -0.349814 + 0.0301436 I, 
   0.840108 + 0. I, -0.358079 - 0.0229246 I, 
   0.0955152 + 0.0804529 I}, {-0.00253399 - 0.0719661 I, 
   0.0113022 + 0.0475596 I, 
   0.00389645 - 0.0167886 I, -0.00429156 + 0.00510902 I, 
   0.00166148 - 0.000734737 I, -0.000470727 - 0.0000705509 I, 
   0.0000855359 + 0.000066461 I, -7.33604*10^-6 - 
    0.0000215169 I, -9.97209*10^-7 + 4.33961*10^-6 I, 
   5.86732*10^-7 - 5.52976*10^-7 I, -1.38467*10^-7 + 2.36119*10^-8 I, 
   0.805934 + 0. I, -0.536402 + 0.107684 I, 
   0.186245 + 0.0501935 I, -0.0554538 - 0.0500129 I, 
   0.00756365 + 0.0188729 I, 
   0.000974495 - 0.00523727 I, -0.000777049 + 0.000930539 I, 
   0.000243554 - 0.0000735791 I, -0.0000481455 - 0.0000128628 I, 
   5.95393*10^-6 + 6.78033*10^-6 I, -2.09565*10^-7 - 
    1.55805*10^-6 I}, {-7.14387*10^-7 - 3.11508*10^-7 I, 
   2.34287*10^-6 + 3.33967*10^-6 I, -1.70002*10^-6 - 
    0.0000200966 I, -0.0000399888 + 0.0000837606 I, 
   0.000320663 - 0.000228999 I, -0.00148637 + 0.000164631 I, 
   0.00482644 + 0.00184217 I, -0.00988419 - 0.0106442 I, 
   0.0104973 + 0.0343516 I, -0.00368235 - 0.0586699 I, -0.0147028 + 
    0.0342975 I, 
   4.43882*10^-6 - 8.65524*10^-6 I, -0.0000434324 + 0.000026573 I, 
   0.000251662 - 5.46439*10^-6 I, -0.0010121 - 0.000563607 I, 
   0.00260183 + 0.00417338 I, -0.000888655 - 
    0.0186437 I, -0.0267204 + 0.0586804 I, 
   0.140318 - 0.114801 I, -0.436109 + 0.103903 I, 
   0.733702 + 0. I, -0.415733 - 0.20996 I}, {3.70775*10^-7 + 
    3.44736*10^-7 I, -5.72806*10^-7 - 
    2.43401*10^-6 I, -3.97703*10^-6 + 0.0000112541 I, 
   0.0000405196 - 0.0000326462 I, -0.000214321 + 0.0000263692 I, 
   0.000738563 + 0.000288755 I, -0.00162487 - 0.00211852 I, 
   0.00215028 + 0.00773783 I, 
   0.00384473 - 0.0174451 I, -0.0209518 + 0.0395755 I, 
   0.00377232 - 0.0505358 I, -4.47615*10^-6 + 5.59781*10^-6 I, 
   0.0000337592 - 0.0000106518 I, -0.000163074 - 0.0000442868 I, 
   0.000503592 + 0.000537642 I, -0.000598135 - 
    0.00299795 I, -0.00329824 + 0.0107312 I, 
   0.0281964 - 0.0251721 I, -0.106975 + 0.0385116 I, 
   0.250337 + 0.0358946 I, -0.580797 - 0.254086 I, 0.717427 + 0. I}}}
```

I want `A[[1]]` to be `{.9704,.9659,.67129,.6513,-.000107+.73i,.000000994+.76i,.0344+1.42i,....}`

Sorry For the mess of data.  I am trying to sort eigenvalues and keep the corresponding eigenvector with them

Comment: how to sort complex numbers? dictionary order? or by Real part? we don't know, need one more concrete question.

Comment: So I want to sort the Real parts in descending order, and then sort so that the imaginary parts are ascending

Comment: Please try to put yourself in an answerer's shoes.  Both this one and your latest question simply can't be answered without more information.  Think about this *before* you post and make sure your questions are clear.  "but that does not sort the complex numbers as I want them to" <-- how should we know how you want them to be sorted?  There's no standard way to sort complex numbers.  If you re-read your question, it should be obvious what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SortBy[{1 + I, 5 + I, what + I, 3 + 4 I, 5}, Re] 
{1+I,3+4 I,5,5+I,I+what}
SortBy[{1 + I, 5 + I, what + I, 3 + 4 I, 5}, Re] // Reverse
{I+what,5+I,5,3+4 I,1+I}
SortBy[{1+I,5+I,what+I,3+4I,5}, Im]
{5,1+I,5+I,3+4 I,I+what}
```

hehe! 
        `A=Table[Reverse[Select[A[[i]],Element[#,Reals]&]] ~Join~ SortBy[Select[A[[i]],!Element[#,Reals]&],Im],{i,Length@A}];`

```
In[47]:= A[[1]]

Out[47]= {0.651301,0.671298,0.965926,0.97048,-0.000107956+0.735512 I,9.93642*10^-6+0.764605 I,0.0344992 +1.4214 I,0.0028631 +1.4505 I,-0.0626803+1.78014 I,-0.12443+1.98252 I,0.167724 +2.24691 I}
```

Comment: I am trying to do it for an arbitraryset of values.  If I have lets say a list named list, that contains: 5, 1+2i, 4, -2 +6i, will that get them in the order 5,4,1+2i,-2+6i ?

Comment: I don't know, you can post some sample data.

Comment: Sorry for the mess of data I edited in

Comment: one way is sort reals and complex seperately and Join them

Comment: Thank you!  This helped a bunch!