# What Mathematica features and idioms have $n^2$ complexity or worse

Tags: programming, performance-tuning

Here are a few: `AppendTo[data, elem]`, `Sort[data, test]`, in some cases use of `___` (as mentioned in David Wagner's book).

**Edit:**

A Wolfram Research developer explains [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Jul/msg00056.html) why `Union[data,test]` has quadratic complexity, and I am pretty sure the same applies to `Sort[data,test]`. The same Wolfram developer explains [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Apr/msg00820.html) that `AppendTo[data,elem]` has quadratic complexity. There are many math problems such as `Inverse[matrix]`, `FactorInteger[n]` that are inherently expensive on large problems.

The most important answers to this question will be features in the core language that can kill the performance of a program. Sometimes you can greatly improve the performance of your program if you avoid such features.

Comment: Ted -- The question might inform a wider audience if you provide some background/explanation of n^2 complexity and it hazards, especially as related to a language like Mathematica, which does so much symbolically.  I can imagine that Mathematica's paradigm might have significant vulnerabilities to cascading into complexity.

Comment: Well, this is going to be a long list. Also: are you sure about `Sort[data,test]`? Generally, sorting is O(n log n). Check out `Trace[Sort[{4, 3, 2, 1}, OrderedQ[{#1, #2}] &]] // Column`. My guess is that _Mathematica_ assumes that the function supplied as the second argument is one that yields an ordering on the supplied list, even though the user is free to supply a function that does not satisfy this. For example: `Sort[{4, 3, 2, 1}, RandomChoice[{True, False}] &]`. _Mathematica_ therefore does not have to compare every two elements. For some fixed tests like `2*Prime[#] < Prime[#2]&` ...

Comment: We already have a "pitfalls" community wiki. I think this fits under that umbrella and would the answer should be made there.

Comment: @m_goldberg Could you provide a link?

Comment: @belisarius. I made my comment when I was half-asleep and now that I re-read it fully awake, I find its not very cogent. What I meant to say was: We already have a "pitfalls" community wiki, and I would prefer see this question treated there as another pitfall, rather than it having a separate existence. I did not mean that it was already answered there.

Comment: Ted, thank you for adding links. I have checked out the one about `AppendTo`. Here however, it is not `AppendTo` that is meant to have quadratic complexity, but rather a construction like `Do[AppendTo[list, f[k]],{k,n}]`. This makes sense if copying a list has order has order n. Then copying a list n times has quadratic complexity.

Comment: Also I am quite sure `Sort` does not have quadratic complexity. Consider the sentence in your first link: "Union will not sort but rather test a given element
against every other (remaining) element". I think the comparison with sort is made to show that in the case of `Union` it is necessary to compare all elements pairwise, whereas this is not the case when you wish to sort. I'm quite sure the guys at Mathematica implemented a fast sort algorithm with good assymptotic properties and the fact that sorting is O(n log (n)) as can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: But again, this assumes that the test in `Sort[data, test]` can be executed in constant time.

Comment: @belisarius the link: [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/4330)

Comment: @m_goldberg I would prefer it if there is a separate Q&A for this matter (as is currently the case). Especially because this complexity stuff tends to confuse people, myself included :). For example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/1381569) most likely confuses the concepts of big O notation and Theta notation and still got 2800 upvotes.

Comment: Would you mind if we change this question to something along the lines of: "What are the complexities of these code snippets?" I think this has to be answered first before moving on to composing lists.

Comment: @Jacob Akkerboom you can change the question to anything you like. Also, I would very much like to have a list of coding practices that are shoe to lead to slow programs in Mathematica.