# How to delete duplicated sublist

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list like this:

```
rew={{{2011, 3, 13, 0, 0, 0}, 1044.4}, {{2011, 3, 13, 3, 0, 0}, Missing["NotAvailable"]}, 
{{2011, 3, 13, 3, 0, 0}, 1044.7}, {{2011, 3, 13, 6, 0, 0}, 1043.4}, 
{{2011, 3, 13, 9, 0, 0},1041.5}, {{2011, 3, 13, 12, 0, 0}, 1044.1}, 
{{2011, 3, 13, 15, 0, 0}, 1045.4}, {{2011, 3, 13, 18, 0, 0}, 1046.8}, 
{{2011, 3, 13, 21, 0, 0}, 1047.5},.....}
```

How do I delete duplicated sublists?

From this list I want to delete

```
 {{2011, 3, 13, 3, 0, 0}, Missing["NotAvailable"]}, {{2011, 3, 13, 3, 0, 0}, 1044.7}
```

this sublists which have duplicates because the first part is the same. And also delete duplicates if I face the duplicates

Comment: what is `{2011, 3, 13, 0, 0, 0}, 1044.4}` a duplicate of?

Comment: Oh sorry, duplication is: {{2011, 3, 13, 3, 0, 0}, Missing["NotAvailable"]}, {{2011, 3, 13, 3, 0, 0}, 1044.7}

Comment: so you want to delete both (all!) entries beginning with `{2011, 3, 13, 3, 0, 0}` (or rather keep one entry?)? Please confirm

Comment: Check if this does what you want: `DeleteCases[GatherBy[rew, First@# &], datum_ /; Length[datum] != 1]`

Comment: I want to keep first one. In other word, There shouldn't be duplicated dates. This list contains date and data. So, Date shouldn't be same.

Comment: @user2987529 In your question it seems you're asking for any element that has been duplicated to be deleted along with its duplicates (which is what my solution in the previous comment does).

Comment: @Aky yes your right. However keeping the first one of duplication is also useful for me.

Comment: @user2987529 `DeleteDuplicates[rew, First@#1 == First@#2 &]`.

Comment: `GatherBy[list, First][[;;, 1]]` the second part of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27274/5478) is yours question.

Comment: You say you want to "keep the first one". Do you really not also want the one that has actual data, instead of `Missing`?