# Is there a function that compares two lists and take from first the element with the position of largest value at second?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Is there a function in Mathematica that compares two lists and take from first the element with the position of largest value at second:

```
  list1= {a,b}; list2={1,2}; out = b
```

Comment: [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) comes to mind: `Pick[list1, list2, Max@list2]`.

Comment: closely related: [Sort lists according to the order of another](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7679/125)

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for one built-in function does this job, I think there's no such function at the moment, but your goal can be easily achieved by

```
list1[[Ordering[list2, -1]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MaximalBy[Transpose[{{a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}}], Last]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realised @Corey979 mentioned the same in comments but my method would use `Pick`

```
list1={a,b,c,d,e}
list2=RandomInteger[10,5] = {0,7,7,9,1}

Pick[list1,list2,Max[list2]]
Out[54]= {d}
```